# jsonMappingException org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at

Tags: java, android, json, mapping

I am getting below exception while parsing-

```
JsonMappingException org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source: [B@3f5fb6a4; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I found several questions with same exception issue but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: obviously, `{ ... }` is not a json array ... then why are you tring to parse it as an array

Comment: @Selvin how should i parse it?glad if u can help me wid detailed answer as i am fresher

Comment: *how should i parse it* as an object not as an array(list) ... so first you should understand jackson mapper - you don't have to understand what is going on internally but **at least understand what given method does** (do not expect to get the code ready to copy&paste from me)

Comment: @Selvin What wrong I am doing.I am creating a list of `UserObject` which has fields id,name and handle.Also `Social` is an object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a JSON **object** as a **list**. Try changing

```
List<Social> topics = objectMapper.readValue(response.data, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Social.class));
```

into something like:

```
Social topics = objectMapper.readValue(response.data, Social.class);
```

Comment: and wht should i replace `protected Response<List<Social>> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) ` and `return Response.success(topics, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));` with?

Comment: The rest of the code can stay as it is. You should only need to change that one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.data);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("newUsers");
List<UserObject > userObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonArray.toString() , new TypeReference<List<UserObject>>(){});
```

for JSONObject use java-json.jar